# How to expand the fieldsets in node-add form?

Tags: 7, forms

When I am adding new node by `admin/content/node-type/story`, there are a lot of settings ordered by groups:  *Submission form settings, workflow setting, comment settings*. But all these fieldsets are all by default collapsed.

My question is: how to make them all default to expanded?

Answer (score 4):

I believe you have one of two options...

1. In Code: Have a look at [hook_form_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_form_alter/6) and modify the applicable field groups to be `$form['the_form_fieldset']['#collapsed'] = FALSE;`
2. In UI: Modify the CCK types form. Go to your content types, click manage fields on the one you want and then select the 'Manage Form' tab.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Would agree. hook_form_alter seems like the cleanest way to go here

Comment: Thanks for reply. But I have a problem.  1 way - manage fields - I can manage only these fields, which I created. About hook form function. As I read, I should edit core.php and find in this file hook_form_alter section, yes? But there is a problem. Where is this file?

Comment: @Tom122345: You will not find any `hook_form_alter()` function, and core.php (or system.api.php) is just a documentation file for the hooks implemented by Drupal core; I don't think you would find that file between the Drupal files. For more information about Drupal hooks, read the [documentation](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--module.inc/group/hooks/6).

Comment: @tom122345: Firstly, you never modify core files: you build modules to capture the functionality you want to achieve. Try a [google search](http://www.google.co.za/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=drupal+building+a+module) and try a few module build tutorials. However, I am not sure why you can't see the additional fields when you go to manage the form.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from implementing `hook_form_alter()` to collapse the form fieldsets present in the node edit form, you can also install and use the [Fieldset helper](http://drupal.org/project/fieldset_helper), which is a module that remember the status of the fieldsets, and restore it every time the page containing them is viewed; this means that if you collapse a fieldset, that fieldset will be always shown as collapsed.
As alternative, you can install [Override Node Options](http://drupal.org/project/override_node_options) that, as secondary feature, it also allows selected field sets to be set as collapsed and/or collapsible.